# Java "For" loop output repeats

Tags: java, for-loop

I am a beginner trying to program a java code to produce output numbers that is a prime factor of two and five.

For example, if input is **8**, then output should be **2 4 5 8**. 
However, whenever I print my output, the result will be 2 5 4 5 8 5.

Please advice on where I have gone wrong.
Thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class twofive {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter n:");
    int n = sc.nextInt();                                                     
    double num = 0; 
    double num2 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; (((Math.pow(2,i))<= n) || ((Math.pow(5,i)) <=n) || (((Math.pow(2,i))<= n) && ((Math.pow(5,i)) <=n))) ; i++) {
      if (( Math.pow(2,i)) <= n)                                                  
        num = (Math.pow(2,i));
      int convert = (int) num;{
        System.out.print(convert + " ");
      }
      if ((Math.pow(5,i)) <= n)
      num2 = (Math.pow(5,i));
      int convert2 = (int) num2;
      {System.out.print(convert2 + " ");  
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The *integer* factors of 8 are **1 2 4 8**. The *prime* factorization of 8 is *2 2 2* or *2^3*. Your code does something else: it produces all *composites* of 2 and 5 (and the primes 2 and 5) less than or equal to a given integer.

Answer (score 0):

After you review @AmedeeVanGasse 's comment, you need to fix your braces.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter n:");
    int n = sc.nextInt();                                                     
    double num = 0; 
    double num2 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; Math.pow(2,i))<= n) || ((Math.pow(5,i)) <=n) || (((Math.pow(2,i))<= n) && ((Math.pow(5,i)) <=n))) ; i++) {
      if (( Math.pow(2,i)) <= n) {                                                 
        num = (Math.pow(2,i));
        int convert = (int) num;
        System.out.print(convert + " ");
      }
      if ((Math.pow(5,i)) <= n) {
          num2 = (Math.pow(5,i));
          int convert2 = (int) num2;
          System.out.print(convert2 + " ");  
      }
   }
}
```

You should also review the logic in your `for` loop and `if` statements. They are full of unneeded redundancies.